# Resize image in css file

Tags: css

I have received a css file as per below. I usually reference the anchor in the html and then format using css however I see here the file is placed using the css file.

I have managed to change the logo file to be our logo however I now need to resize the logo as it is too big.

**CSS**

```
#header {
  display: block;
  background: #446e9b;
  color: white;
}
#header::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 3.8em;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
#header .home {
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #395c82;
  border-left: 1px solid #395c82;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1px;
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}
#header .home:before {
/* content: url(../images/logo.svg); */
  content: url(/images/logo.png);
}
#header .home:hover, #header .home:active {
  background: rgba(71, 77, 87, 0.5);
}
#header #quick-search {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.65em;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
#header #quick-search .icon-search:before {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.4em;
  top: 0.2em;
  color: #474d57;
}
#header #quick-search #q {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding-left: 2em !important;
  border-color: rgba(71, 77, 87, 0.5);
  padding: 0.4em;
  width: 10em;
  background: rgba(71, 77, 87, 0.3);
  box-shadow: none !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
#header #quick-search #q:active, #header #quick-search #q:focus {
  color: #333333;
  background: white;
  width: 15em;
}
#header a, #header .icon-add.checklist-new-only, #header a:hover, #header .icon-add.checklist-new-only:hover, #header a:active, #header .icon-add.checklist-new-only:active, #header a:focus, #header .icon-add.checklist-new-only:focus {
  color: white;
}
#header .select2-container {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
#header .select2-container .select2-chosen {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
#header .select2-container .select2-choice {
  background: rgba(71, 77, 87, 0.3);
  border-color: rgba(71, 77, 87, 0.5);
  box-shadow: none !important;
  height: 2.2em;
}
#header .select2-container .select2-arrow {
  border-color: rgba(71, 77, 87, 0.5);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">

    <a href="#" class="mobile-toggle-button js-flyout-menu-toggle-button"></a>

    <% if User.current.logged? || !Setting.login_required? %>
    <div id="quick-search">
        <%= form_tag({:controller => 'search', :action => 'index', :id => @project}, :method => :get ) do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(controller.default_search_scope, 1, :id => nil) if controller.default_search_scope %>
        <label for='q'>
          <%= link_to l(:label_search), {:controller => 'search', :action => 'index', :id => @project}, :accesskey => accesskey(:search) %>:
        </label>
        <%= text_field_tag 'q', @question, :size => 20, :class => 'small', :accesskey => accesskey(:quick_search) %>
        <% end %>
        <%= render_project_jump_box %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <h1><%= page_header_title %></h1>
    <% if display_main_menu?(@project) %>
    <div id="main-menu" class="tabs">
        <%= render_main_menu(@project) %>
        <div class="tabs-buttons" style="display:none;">
            <button class="tab-left" onclick="moveTabLeft(this); return false;"></button>
            <button class="tab-right" onclick="moveTabRight(this); return false;"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Some markup would be helpful.

Comment: The question is not clear, it is better to add  your markup (html) too

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is the code in question:

```
#header .home:before {
/*content: url(../images/logo.svg);*/
  content: url(/images/logo.png);
}
```

To resize this, you could:

```
#header .home:before {
  content: '';

  background-image: url('/images/logo.png');
  background-size: ...;
}
```

That aside, your question is quite unclear.

Comment: I had previously tried using width & height as suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: Then use `background-image`.

Comment: I'm confused. As you suggested using width why does it not work?

Comment: Nevermind the first method. It won't work in your case. You won't be able to resize the image if you use `content: url()`. Instead, use `background-image: url()` as I suggested. `content: ''` has to be set for the pseudo-element to be rendered. Then use `background-size: %` to resize the image.